# How to add a sprite from another class on the gameScene

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, sknode

can anyone explain how to add a node to the gameScene please.

I subclassed my  Boss class but i dont know how i can display my Boss1 on the GameScene

```
class Boss: GameScene {
    var gameScene : GameScene!
    var Boss1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "boss1")

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        Boss1.position = CGPoint(x: size.width * 0.1, y: size.height * 0.5)
        Boss1.zPosition = 2

        self.gameScene.addChild(Boss1)  
    }   
}
```

im using swift 4 and xcode 9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't generally subclass the scene for instances such as this. More likely you are meaning to make boss a subclass of `SKSpriteNode` and adding it to your scene. While there is probably dozens of ways that you could subclass this, this is just 1 way.

Also worth noting that it is not generally acceptable practice to make your variable names capitalized, classes yes, variables no.

```
class Boss: SKSpriteNode {

    init() {

        let texture = SKTetxure(imageNamed: "boss1")
        super.init(texture: texture , color: .clear, size: texture.size())

        zPosition = 2
        //any other setup such as zRotation coloring, additional layers, health etc.
    }   
}
```

> ...meanwhile back in GameScene

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    let boss1: Boss!

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        boss1 = Boss()
        boss1.position = CGPoint(x: size.width * 0.1, y: size.height * 0.5)
        self.gameScene.addChild(boss1)  
    }   
}
```

in GameScene you create an instance of the new class and position it and add it in the GameScene.

> edit

the init function has a short cut in swift.

```
Boss()
```

is the same as

```
Boss.init()
```

you can also add custom parameters to your init in order to further clarify or add more features to your class. for example...

```
class Boss: SKSpriteNode {

    private var health: Int = 0

    init(type: Int, health: Int, scale: CGFloat) {

        let texture: SKTetxure!

        if type == 1 {
            texture = SKTetxure(imageNamed: "boss1")
        }
        else {
            texture = SKTetxure(imageNamed: "boss2")
        }
        super.init(texture: texture , color: .clear, size: texture.size())

        self.health = health
        self.setScale(scale)
        zPosition = 2
        //any other setup such as zRotation coloring, additional layers, health etc.
    }   
}
```

Comment: thanks you for reply it worded perfectly  but i dont get how to use the init could you please explain it to me

Comment: I've tried to explain the init more in my answer. I've added an edit at the bottom